# React & SVG: How do I make <path> support onClick?

Tags: svg, onclick, reactjs

This is what React SVG currently supports: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#svg-attributes

I'm trying to figure out how to make a shape I drew using the SVG path clickable.
If there is another way to draw a shape that can be made clickable, that works too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
svg {
    pointer-events: none;
}

path{
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Then we can add on click event on path. worked!! thanks

Answer (score 4):

I wrap my SVG with a div and apply any attributes that I desire (click handlers, fill colors, classes, width, etc..), [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/78043/) (fiddle link):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

function XMark({ width, height, fill, onClick }) {
    return (
        <div className="xmark-container" onClick={onClick}>
            <svg className='xmark' viewBox="67 8 8 8" width={width} height={height} version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <polygon stroke="none" fill={fill} fillRule="evenodd" points="74.0856176 9.4287633 71.5143809 12 74.0856176 14.5712367 73.5712367 15.0856176 71 12.5143809 68.4287633 15.0856176 67.9143824 14.5712367 70.4856191 12 67.9143824 9.4287633 68.4287633 8.91438245 71 11.4856191 73.5712367 8.91438245 74.0856176 9.4287633 74.0856176 9.4287633 74.0856176 9.4287633" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}
XMark.propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.number,
    height: PropTypes.number,
    fill: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
}
XMark.defaultProps = {
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    fill: '#979797',
    onClick: null,
}
export default XMark
```

You can of course ditch the wrapper and apply the onClick to the `svg` element as well, but I've found this approach works well for me!
(I also try and use pure functions when possible https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc)

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

Just using `polyline` for example, it could be any SVG element.

```
export default class Polyline extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.polyline.addEventListener('click', this.props.onClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.polyline.removeEventListener('click', this.props.onClick);
    }

    render() {
        const {points, style, markerEnd} = this.props;
        return <polyline points={points}
                     ref={ref => this.polyline = ref}
                     style={style}
                     markerEnd={markerEnd}/>;
    }
}
```

- get ref in ref callback
- on componentDidMount add click event listener to the ref
- remove event listener in componentWillUnmount

Comment: Quote from [react doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html): "_When using React you should generally not need to call addEventListener to add listeners to a DOM element after it is created. Instead, just provide a listener when the element is initially rendered._" Isn't there a better way?

Comment: We should avoid `addEventListener` in React. 'onClick' works well with SVG elements.

Comment: Interesting that you can assign event listeners directly on the flattened polygon svg shape.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with react, I was trying to handle onclick event for svg.

Simple css solved problem for me:

```
svg {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It would be better as a comment on the question, noting that it might fix some issues in some (archaic) browsers.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. While I agree this doesn't answer the question. I would say if the svg is just for decoration and a child of the element you which to capture an event on this does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onClick` as you do with other DOM elements.

Comment: `onClick` works well with SVG in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Two major ways to do this:

1. You put an HTML event listener on the 'path' tag in the svg code. You will have to escape your code properly if you choose this method.
   The following example features a star shape cut in two paths each of which logs "Hello" in the console ( console.log("Hello") )
   Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 225 213.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 225 213.6;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#4D4D4D;}
    .st1{fill:#494949;}
</style>
<g>
    <path id="right" onmouseover="console.log(&quot;Hello&quot;)" class="st0" d="M43.5,131c4.4,4.2,6.3,8.7,5,15.1
        c-3.4,17.2-6,34.6-9,51.9c-1.5,8.5,1.6,14.4,9.1,15.5c3.1,0.5,6.8-0.9,9.8-2.4c14.9-7.6,29.8-15.4,44.5-23.5c3-1.6,5.8-2.5,8.6-2.7
        V0.1c-1.1,0.2-2.1,0.5-3.2,1.1c-2.7,1.4-5.2,4.2-6.7,7c-7.8,15.2-15.6,30.5-22.8,46C75.6,61,71,64.7,63.5,65.7
        c-16.6,2.2-33.1,5.1-49.7,6.9C6.4,73.5,2.4,77.2,0,83.5c0,0.7,0,1.3,0,2c3.5,4.5,6.7,9.4,10.7,13.4C21.4,109.8,32.5,120.4,43.5,131
        z"/>
    <path id="left" onmouseover="console.log(&quot;Hello&quot;)" class="st1" d="M206.4,71.9c-15.9-2.1-31.8-4.7-47.7-6.9c-5.3-0.7-8.8-3.5-11-8.2c-8-16.2-16-32.5-24.1-48.7
        c-2.9-5.8-7.3-8.8-12-8v184.8c3.5-0.2,6.9,0.7,10.6,2.7c14.7,8.1,29.6,15.8,44.5,23.5c2.9,1.5,6.7,2.9,9.8,2.4
        c7.3-1,10.5-6.8,9.2-15c-3-17.8-5.9-35.6-9.2-53.3c-1.1-5.6,0.7-9.8,4.5-13.4c11.2-10.9,22.6-21.7,33.6-32.8c4-4,7.1-8.9,10.7-13.4
        c0-0.7,0-1.3,0-2C222.3,74.1,214.5,72.9,206.4,71.9z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Example: https://svgshare.com/i/aex.svg

2. In Adobe Illustrator there is (currently called) SVG Iteractivity tool.
   You can find it under the Window top menu.
   Then select the path you need with direct selection tool, choose the HTML event from the SVG Interactivity widow and write your Javascript Code below.
   Then click 'Export Selection' from the file menu or Save As... and save all as .svg

The result will be .svg file with automatically properly escaped code and HTML event on the 'path' tag.